# C# how do i calculate and add to the string odd and even parity from a binary string

Tags: c#

How do i calculate and add to the string odd and even parity from a binary string:

26-Bit Wiegand Format:

Bit 1 = Even Parity over Bits 2 - 13

Bits 26 Odd parity over bits 14 to 25

Ex: 
binary string: 1111 1011 0111 0111 1111 1010

after odd and even calculation: X 1111 1011 0111 0111 1111 1010 Y

Comment: What have you tried thus far and where are you stuck?  SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: A stack could be useful here. Go through each character in the string, push if it's a 1, pop if it's 0. If your stack ends up empty then you've got even parity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a binary string:

```
var bitString = "10101";
```

You can get the parity with a bit of LINQ:

```
int bitCount = bitString.Where( c => c == '1' ).Count(); //Count the bits that are set
bool parityOdd = (bitCount & 1) == 1; //See if the count of set bits itself has its low bit set
```

Comment: Ty John Wu!! Perfect